# Youtube API v3 Videos Endpoint mostPopular getting only 30 results

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api

Did someone realized lately that Youtube API v3 is returning only 30 results when you fetch mostPopular videos of a region ? Even if you set maxResults to 50 (which is the biggest acceptable value), the API returs only 30 videos without nextPageToken parameter.

Please help :(